# RJ45 CAT 5 LAN Ethernet splitter Connector problems

Tags: networking, home-networking

Can I use different IP addresses on two different ports dividing by using a RJ45 CAT 5 LAN Ethernet splitter Connector?

Answer (score 2):

An Ethernet splitter just lets two 10Mbps or 100Mbps Ethernet lines run over a single cable. They must be used in pairs. They don't divide ports.

So, for example, say you had two switch ports in one room connected to two devices in another room with two cables. You could connect both switch ports to one side of a splitter and both devices to one side of another splitter. You could then connect the two splitters together with a single cable and have two 100Mbps Ethernet links without having to have two long cables.

That's all Ethernet splitters do. They do not allow two devices to connect to the same switch or router port.